# Hello, can some one help me

Tags: connection, timeout

```
00:00:01,564 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.client] (Thread-11 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=a515fe69-fa14-11e5-8ce4-d54dd29e8524-1886871820)) HQ214016: Failed to create netty connection: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
  at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(OioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:109) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(OioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:69) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

You failed to connect to your destination. Nobody can tell you anything different without some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server is not running or you are giving wrong server info so you are getting

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

If you attach your code snippet it would be helpful